# Чтение файла Java

Tags: java, файлы

Есть файл, размером 141387112 байт, использую ByteBuffer метод getInt();
Получаю первое число, это число = кол-ву точек. Кол-во точек умножаю на 12, по 3 флоат на точку, и по 4 байта на каждый флоат. После считывания и записи в массив следующий getInt должен вернуть мне целочисленное число, но возвращает огроменное число, выходящие за пределы кол-ва. Помогите решить проблему с неправильным считыванием.

```
try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(myFile)) {
            //получаем размер файла
            System.out.println("Размер файла: " + fin.available() + " байт");
            //задаем размер для буфера
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
            //считываем и заносим в буфер
            fin.read(buffer, 0, fin.available());
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
            count_points = bb.getInt(); // кол-во точек
            bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            Log.w("W","кол-во точек = " + count_points);
            //переводим это кол-во в байты
            count_mul = count_points * 12;
            Log.w("W","кол-во байт которые занимают точки = " + count_mul);
            //обьявляем массив размерностью точек
            mass_vertices = new float[count_points * 3]; //NEW было count_mul стало  count_points * 3
            //Заносим в массив
            int p =0;
            for(int i = 0; i < count_points * 3 ; i ++) {
                mass_vertices[i] = bb.getFloat();
                p+=4;
            }
            bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
            Log.w("W","кол-во цветных точек = " + bb.getInt());
            Log.w("W","кол-во счит байтов = " + p);
            Log.w("W","X = " + mass_vertices[0]);
            Log.w("W","Y = " + mass_vertices[1]);
            Log.w("W","Z = " + mass_vertices[2]);
```

Лог:

```
СЧИТЫВАЕМ ФАЙЛ
 I/System.out: 
 Размер файла: 141387112 байт
 W/W: кол-во точек = 793974
 W/W: кол-во байт которые занимают точки = 9527688
 кол-во цветных точек = 70256
 W/W: кол-во счит байтов = 9527688
 W/W: X = 18230.195
 W/W: Y = 21232.865
 W/W: Z = 0.0
 E/E: __________________________________
```

Comment: Ну а что же вы хотели то? У вас 140 мегов, 3 точки по 4 байта - дают как раз что-то в районе 10m точек. Вы все равно не сможете 140 мегов запихнуть в память

Comment: А при чем тут побитовое чтение?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов дело в том, что файл бинарный, и не содержит в себе текста и т.д, грубо говоря разделителем является то самое число Int, которое указывает сколько байт нужно считать и преобразовать для этого сегмента, и после этого сегмента снова стоит число Int, которое указывает на тоже самое, получить данные оттуда можно только побитово считывая его.

Comment: Не побитово, а побайтово :)

Comment: @Barmaley Не, в логах например указано кол-во точек 793 тысчи, это первый массив, следующее кол-во точек, это второй массив, как видите целочисленное число не может быть впринципе отрицательным) И даже указывая с какого байта читать файл, число либо получается нереально большим, либо отрицательным.

Comment: "Кол-во точек умножаю на 12, по 3 флоат на точку, и по 4 байта на каждый флоат" - умножение на 4 здесь как-то сомнительно. То, что у вас одна координата занимает 4 байта - не повод читать 4 четырехбайтных числа.

Comment: `bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);` посреди кода тоже вызывает подозрения. Обычно порядок старшинства байт не меняется в середине потока, а тут вы сперва считали число точек, потом поменяли порядок (по-умолчанию там `BIG_ENDIAN`), потом опять считали число точек.

Comment: @zRrr По умолчанию BIG_ENDIAN, да, но вот проблема почему то такая, если не указать что мы идем "От младшего к старшему" float-ы считываются не правильно, и следующий int тоже, по этому приходится указывать LITTLE_ENDIAN после считывания int, после считывания float снова указать BIG_ENDIAN